# python script keeps using 120% CPU

Tags: python, performance, file-io, python-2.7

I'm having an issue with my websocket script. Over time it consumes more and more CPU. One remedy I've discovered is to clear the associated logfile. This resolves the problem for a little while, but the CPU usuage builds up to 120% in little over a day or so. (using the top command on the linux server)

The part of the script that does the file write looks a bit odd to me. Here is the code:

```
 f = open(file, 'a')
 f.write(line+"\n")
 os.fsync(f.fileno())
 f.flush()
 f.close
```

I'm not a Python expert, but for starters, the last three things do rather the same in my opinion. The python manual states http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.fsync that f.flush and os.fsync should be in reverse order...

Can I just use:

```
 f = open(file, 'a')
 f.write(line+"\n")
 f.close
```

and should it not be: f.close()??

Any ideas?

Comment: You are never closing your file, yes it should be `f.close()`

Comment: You're right in that a `close()` implies a `flush()`, and I've no idea what `fsync()` is meant to accomplish if you're already working on a file object and not on the raw handles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this to open (and automatically close) your files:

```
with open(filename, 'a') as f:
    f.write(line+"\n")
```

Comment: Even with this modification, the script still eats CPU like mad. It is the correct answer, so I'll accept it.